# Get typescript default/initial argument type in order to extend it

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql-js

I'm working on some code that auto-generates type hints based on function calls (GraphQL Nexus stuff).

Then, in one of it's functions, it expects an anonymous type based on those auto-generated attributes:

```js
export const Item = {
  isTypeOf(data) {  // data's type is an anonymous type, here it would be '{ name: string }'
    ...
  }
  definition(t) {
    t.string('name')
  }
}
```

However, this `data` argument may contain more variables than the ones defined by the function calls. In my case, I need to access a `kind` property, but I can't call the `t._type_` function because it would have undesired side-effects.

I also can't just pass the type as `{ kind: string }` since `isTypeOf` type expects it to have at least all defined properties on it's arguments.

I could just use `{ name: string, kind: string }` in this example, but my actual code contains more complex objects, and I would lose all the benefits of the auto-generated typing stuff.

Is there any way for me to in-line extend an argument with anonymous type? I was thinking something like an `initial` or `default` keyword to get an argument's own type, and use it like this:

```js
isTypeOf(data: initial & { kind: string })
isTypeOf(data: default & { kind: string })
```

Comment: like `typeof data & {kind: string}`?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not care about additional keys in objects passed to function (unless created in the parameter list).

If you only want to accept objects with given property and **not return** it, use the definition of `isTypeOf`.

If you need to return the same type and possibly extend it use the definition of `definition`.

```
export const Item = {
  isTypeOf(data: { kind: string }): boolean {
    return data.kind == '...';
  },
  definition<T extends { string: (key: string): void }>(t): T & { defined: true } {
    t.string('name');
    (t as T & { defined: true }).defined = true;

    return t;
  },
};

const myType = {
  kind: 'hello',
  name: 'World',
  string(key: string): {},
};

Item.isTypeOf(myType); // OK
Item.isTypeOf({ kind: 'hello', name: 'World' }); // Not OK

Item.definition(myType); // OK
Item.definition({ string(key: string): {} }); // OK
```

Comment: Maybe I forgot to explain in my answer, but the `isTypeOf` has a pre-defined type definition which requires it to have all properties defined inside `definition` on it's argument. Also, the function is being called with all defined arguments, plus some extra ones such as `kind`. I don't have issues having type errors on the caller, since it's from the lib side, but I want to be able to do type checking on all defined properties plus some additional ones, such as `kind` inside the `isTypeOf` function.

Comment: I don't understand. Give us more code examples of what you need. To me, this answers your question for now :( What are the output types of your functions? What are the inputs you would like to put there?

Comment: `isTypeOf` must match a definition of `function(data: { (auto-generated-type) }: boolean`. The lib sends to the function all values defined on `definition` plus some extra stuff. All I want is to be able to cast the argument type to the defined properties + some additional properties. Your solution fails on the first example because it does not match the `isTypeOf` definition, and the second has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Can you edit what the `{ (auto-generated-type) }` will be? Can you for example do `{ generatedType: ... } & { kind: string }`